# Setting turtle coordinates to patch color in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I'm working through creating my first Netlogo model and I'm trying to create a turtle only on patches that have a certain color

```
 create-h2o (totalmoles * h20number / 100)[
    set shape "circle"
    set color black
    set size 0.2
    setxy one-of patches with [pcolor = liquid]
  ]
```

which doesn't work as setxy needs an X and a Y coordinate

I've also tried creating the turtles at randomxy coordinates and then moving them to patches

```
setxy random xcor random ycor
move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = liquid]
```

right after, but I get an error that "MOVE-TO expected input to be an agent but got NOBODY instead"

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the second doesn't work is because there is no such colour as 'liquid' so `patches with [pcolor = liquid]` is empty. But the approach is fine. Simply replace that with a real color and it will work.

You might also want to look up `sprout` to create your turtles. In this case it's probably better to stick with your approach because it looks like you will be having some random number of h20 turtles on the water patches.

Comment: If I have a global variable for liquid, would that work as well?

Comment: yes, as long as you set it to a real colour (a named colour like `blue` or a number) then that will be fine